# Sobrecarga de operador + en C++

Tags: c++, poo, class, operador, sobrecarga-de-operadores

No consigo sacar el operador +, ¿Cómo puedo hacer una sobrecarga del operador + para que sume el valor de dos dados y devuelva un entero con el resultado?

Esta es la clase:

```
class Dado{

private:
  int dado_;

public:
  Dado();
  Dado(int valor);

  inline int get(){
    return dado_;
  }

  inline bool set(int dado){
    if(dado<=6 and dado>=1){
      dado_=dado;
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  }
};
```

Este el archivo dados.cc:

```
Dado::Dado()
{
dado1_=1;
}
Dado::Dado(int valor){
  if(valor>6 or valor<1){
    dado_=1;
  }
  else{
    dado_=valor;
  }

}
```

Esto es lo que me pide el enunciado: Sobrecarga del operador + para que sume el valor de dos dados y devuelva un entero con el resultado.

Así es como lo intenté hacer:

```
Dado & operator+(Dado const & d){ 
    int dado2; set(dado2); 
    d.get()+dado2.get(); 
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: ¿donde esta tu intento fallido?

Comment: Se me ha olvidado incluirlo, perdona. Así es como lo intenté hacer: Dado & operator+(Dado const & d){
    int dado2;
    set(dado2);
    d.get()+dado2.get();

    return *this;

  }

Comment: edita tu pregunta y añadelo alli, ademas señala claramente cual es el error

Comment: Eso pensaba, pero es lo que me pide el ejercicio que debo entregar :(

Comment: Quizas hayas entendido mal, re-lee bien tu pregunta :)

Comment: Este es el enunciado:La clase Dado gestiona el lanzamiento de 1 dado.
a) El constructor recibe 1 parámetro opcional con el valor inicial para el dado.
b) Observador get().
c) Modificador set(). Recibe un parámetro con el valor entero a asignar al dado. Control de
errores: si se produce algún error en el valor asignado (debe estar entre 1 y 6), set() debe
devolver false y no modificar el dado, en caso contrario set() modifica el dado y devuelve true.
d) Sobrecarga del operador + para que sume el valor de dos dados y devuelva un entero con el
resultado.

Comment: los comentarios no sirven para dar información relevante, edita tu pregunta y añadelo, ademas lee [ask] y pasa el [tour] :)

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta podrías ser mas especifico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tú operador debe retornar un `int` pero tu estas señalando que estas devolviendo un `Dado`, debes cambiarlo, aqui te muestro un ejemplo:

**dado.h**

```
#ifndef DADO_H
#define DADO_H

class Dado{
    int _valor;
public:
    Dado(int valor=1);
    int getValor() const;
    bool setValor(int valor);
    int operator+(const Dado & d2);
};
#endif // DADO_H
```

**dado.cpp**

```
#include "dado.h"

Dado::Dado(int valor):
    _valor(valor)
{
}

int Dado::getValor() const
{
    return _valor;
}

bool Dado::setValor(int valor)
{
    if(valor < 1 || valor > 6)
        return false;
    _valor = valor;
    return true;
}

int Dado::operator+(const Dado &d2){
    return getValor() + d2.getValor();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "dado.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    Dado d1;
    assert(d1.getValor() == 1);
    d1.setValor(10);
    assert(d1.getValor() == 1);
    Dado d2;
    d2.setValor(4);
    assert(d2.getValor() == 4);
    int respuesta = d1+d2;
    assert(respuesta == 1+4);
    std::cout << respuesta<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

```
Dado & operator+(Dado const & d){ 
    int dado2; set(dado2); 
    d.get()+dado2.get(); 
    return *this;
}
```

Este operador no va a cumplir con su función por tres motivos:

- Te piden que devuelvas el resultado en un entero y tu estás devolviendo un dado
- El operdor `+` **no debe** modificar el estado de ninguno de los dos dados. Para esto está el operador `+=`
- El operador, tal y como está declarado, no es una función miembro de `Dado`, por lo que tendrás que pasarle los dos Dados.

Los dos primeros puntos creo que se entienden bastante bien, si te piden un entero y tu devuelves un objeto de tipo `Dado`, la interfaz de la función no es la correcta y sobre modificar objetos, creo que también está claro.

Algunos operadores en C++ pueden (o no) ser miembros de una clase. Las diferencias básicas son las siguientes:

- Si se implementa como función miembro te puedes ahorrar un parámetro.
- Si se implementa como función miembro puedes acceder a las partes protegidas y privadsa.
- Si se implementa como función libre ganas libertad y reduces el acoplamiento.
- Hay casos en los que no se puede implementar el operador como función miembro.

Un ejemplo práctico:

```
struct POO
{
  int offset;

  // Operador miembro
  int operator+(int n) const 
  { return offset + n; }
};

// Función libre, nota que tiene 2 parámetros
int operator-(POO p, int n)
{ return p.offset - n; }

// Función libre
// No se podría implementar como función miembro
int operator+(int n, POO p)
{ std::cout << "operador libre: " << n + p.offset << '\n'; }

int main()
{
  POO p;
  p.offset = 10;

  std::cout << p + 5 << '\n'; // imprime "15"
  std::cout << p - 5 << '\n'; // imprime "5"
  std::cout << 5 + p << '\n'; // imprime "operador libre: 15"
}
```

Así pues tu sobrecarga del operador +  podrías implementarla de dos formas diferentes:

**Función miembro**

```
class Dado{
public:
  int operator+(Dado const& d2) const;
};

int Dado::operator+(Dado const& d2) const{
  return _valor + d2._valor;
}
```

Nota que la función termina en `const`, esta coletilla fuerza al compilador a mostrar un error en tiempo de compilación si intentas modificar el estado del objeto, por ejemplo haciendo `this->_valor = 10;`.

**Función libre**

```
int operator+(Dado const& d1, Dado const& d2)
{
  return d1.getValor() + d2.getValor();
}
```

En este caso la función no puede ser `const` ya que no pertenece a ninguna clase (por algo es una función libre). Sin embargo ambos parámetros sí que son `const`, por lo que no podrás modificarlos.

El resultado en ambos casos es el mismo, puedes elegir el que más te guste.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu explicación, me ha quedado mucho más claro!